# $\mathbb{R}P^2$ and its lines

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

I have been solving some past exam questions and I came across the following question. Let $r$ and $s$ two distinct lines in $\mathbb{R}P^2$, and let $X$ the space obtained contracting $r \cup s$ to a point in $\mathbb{R}P^2$. Say if $X$ is a topological manifold.
I can not imagine what $X$ is, and i think this is my problem.
Help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a line in $RP^2$? Do you mean the image of a hyperplane in $R^3$ under the quotient map $R^3\to RP^2$?

Comment: @StefanH. $\mathbb RP^2$ is the "real projective plane," and yes, your definition is (one) definition of a line in the "real projective plane."

Comment: $\mathbb R^3-\{0\} \to\mathbb RP^2$ :) Certainly that's the standard use of the terminology for lines in $\mathbb RP^2$, and similarly for $k$-dimensional "planes" in $\mathbb RP^n$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Yes, of course I meant $R^3-\{0\}$. Often forget to exclude the zero :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contracting one line to a point gives a sphere. (Why?) Contracting two lines then is equivalent to contracting one loop on a sphere to a point. What do you think you'll get?

Comment: Perhaps it would be clearer to say that we're contracting a *circle* on a sphere to a point.

Comment: Except it might not be a "circle," either. It's really a simple loop. But yeah.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb RP^2$ as a closed hemisphere with the opposite points of the rim identified. Then the rim is the line at infinity, and contracting the rim to a point is just the same as contracting the rim of the hemisphere to a point.

Comment: So, by contracting the rim i get a sphere. I am not clear what I get contracting a circle in the sphere...the sphere itself?

Comment: Definitely not the sphere itself. If you remove a point from the sphere, is it still connected? If you contract $Y\subset X$ to a point, then remove that point, the space is homeomorphic to $X\setminus Y$...

Comment: Then the resulting space is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (via stereographic projection)?

Comment: No, what happens when you remove a simple loop from a sphere? Do you get a connected space?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what you mean. No, it's not connected. I think that the results is (homotopically equivalent to) two copies of the sphere, joined at the point that was the equator. Is it right?

Comment: Bingo. Exactly. Which is the same as Lano's answer, but he uses the term "wedge sum of two spheres."

Comment: Finally i got there!Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The result is the wedge sum of two copy of $S^2$, thus it's not a topological manifold for obvious problems in the pasting point.

Comment: Thanks Lano!I finally understood!

Comment: You're welcome !